# How to post JSON using Retrofit 2 in android?

Tags: android, json, http-post, retrofit2

**I am new to android and I dont know how to POST using retrofit**

I have my own server which returns me data, I need to fetch that one

This is how URL body looks like
[image]

I have to send "city name" taken by edittext and pass it inside "ms_data's" keyword, i.e keyword="India"

This is what I have tried so far...

*Retrofit Builder class*

```
public class RetrofitBuilder {

public static Retrofit retrofit;

public static final String BASE_URL = "my url";

public static Retrofit getApiData()
{

    if(retrofit==null)
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

*POJO class*

```
public class MessageFromServer {

private String city_name;

public MessageFromServer(String city_name) {
            this.city_name = city_name;
}

public String getCity_name() {
    return city_name;
}

public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
    this.city_name = city_name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MessageFromServer that = (MessageFromServer) o;

    return city_name != null ? city_name.equals(that.city_name) : that.city_name == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return city_name != null ? city_name.hashCode() : 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MessageFromServer{" +
            "city_name='" + city_name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

*RequestBean class*

```
public class JsonRequestBean {

private  String userId;
private String sessionToken;
private String clientType;
private String msServiceType;
private String msService;
private  String searchedLoc = null;
private List<String> msdata = null;




public List<String> getMsdata() {
    return msdata;
}

public void setMsdata(List<String> msdata) {
    this.msdata = msdata;
}


public JsonRequestBean() {
}

public JsonRequestBean(String userId, String sessionToken, String 
clientType, String msServiceType, String msService, String 
serachedLoc) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.sessionToken = sessionToken;
    this.clientType = clientType;
    this.msServiceType = msServiceType;
    this.msService = msService;
    this.searchedLoc = serachedLoc;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getSessionToken() {
    return sessionToken;
}

public void setSessionToken(String sessionToken) {
    this.sessionToken = sessionToken;
}

public String getClientType() {
    return clientType;
}

public void setClientType(String clientType) {
    this.clientType = clientType;
}

public String getMsServiceType() {
    return msServiceType;
}

public void setMsServiceType(String msServiceType) {
    this.msServiceType = msServiceType;
}

public String getMsService() {
    return msService;
}

public void setMsService(String msService) {
    this.msService = msService;
}

public String getSerachedLoc() {
    return searchedLoc;
}

public void setSerachedLoc(String serachedLoc) {
    this.searchedLoc = serachedLoc;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    JsonRequestBean that = (JsonRequestBean) o;

    if (userId != null ? !userId.equals(that.userId) : that.userId != 
null) return false;
    if (sessionToken != null ? !sessionToken.equals(that.sessionToken) 
: that.sessionToken != null)
        return false;
    if (clientType != null ? !clientType.equals(that.clientType) : 
that.clientType != null)
        return false;
    if (msServiceType != null ? 
!msServiceType.equals(that.msServiceType) : that.msServiceType != 
null)
        return false;
    if (msService != null ? !msService.equals(that.msService) : 
that.msService != null)
        return false;
    return searchedLoc != null ? searchedLoc.equals(that.searchedLoc) 
: that.searchedLoc == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (sessionToken != null ? 
sessionToken.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (clientType != null ? clientType.hashCode() 
: 0);
    result = 31 * result + (msServiceType != null ? 
msServiceType.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (msService != null ? msService.hashCode() : 
0);
    result = 31 * result + (searchedLoc != null ? 
searchedLoc.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "JsonRequestBean{" +
            "userId='" + userId + '\'' +
            ", sessionToken='" + sessionToken + '\'' +
            ", clientType='" + clientType + '\'' +
            ", msServiceType='" + msServiceType + '\'' +
            ", msService='" + msService + '\'' +
            ", serachedLoc=" + searchedLoc +
            '}';
}

private class Msdata {

    public String keyword;

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }
}
}
```

ResponseBean class 
//to fetch and store so that i can use however i need

```
public class JsonResponseBean {

@SerializedName("city_name")
@Expose
public String cityName;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public String id;


public JsonResponseBean(String cityName, String id) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
    this.id = id;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public JsonResponseBean() {
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    JsonResponseBean that = (JsonResponseBean) o;

    if (cityName != null ? !cityName.equals(that.cityName) : 
 that.cityName != null)
        return false;
    return id != null ? id.equals(that.id) : that.id == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = cityName != null ? cityName.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "JsonRequestBean{" +
            "cityName='" + cityName + '\'' +
            ", id='" + id + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

//inner class, you can see the image
// i generated this using [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://jsonschema2pojo.org)

```
 class errorCode
 {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    public List<JsonResponseBean> data = null;
    @SerializedName("error_code")
    @Expose
    public String errorCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    public String message;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    public String status;

}
```

API Class

```
public interface APIRequest {

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json","Accept: 
application/json"})
@POST("/lfs/city_name")
Call<JsonResponseBean> locData (@Body JsonRequestBean mRequest);
}
```

DisplayActivity where i get the actual data

// as soon as i open the activty, onfailure will be called

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static TextView tvM,tvN;
private Button btnFetch;
private EditText etCity;
private static final String TAG = "DisplayActivity";
private static final String VALUE = "displaytest";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    init();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String text = i.getStringExtra("HESRU");
    tvN.setText(text);
     String city_name = etCity.getText().toString();
    final List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>() ;
     cityList.add(city_name);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: city name-"+city_name);


    btnFetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitBuilder.getApiData();
            APIRequest service = retrofit.create(APIRequest.class);

            JsonRequestBean jsonRequestBean = new JsonRequestBean();
            jsonRequestBean.setClientType("mobile");
            jsonRequestBean.setMsServiceType("search");
            jsonRequestBean.setMsService("locality");
            jsonRequestBean.setMsdata(cityList);

            Call<JsonResponseBean> responseBeanCall = 
service.locData(jsonRequestBean);
            responseBeanCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponseBean>() 
{
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponseBean> call, 
Response<JsonResponseBean> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: 
"+response.isSuccessful());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:, responebody---
"+response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponseBean> call, 
Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: message"+t.getMessage() );
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "something 
went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });


}
public void init() {
    tvM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMSG);
    tvN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewName);
    btnFetch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonfetch);
    etCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
}
```

Please help to solve this, i found that I should use HttpUrlConnection, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Can you post the failure message?

Comment: 09-11 16:40:26.158 8720-8720/com.example.testdata E/DisplayActivity: onFailure: messageunexpected end of stream on Connection{url, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/url cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

Comment: Do u need full logcat? if so i dont know how to post that! i can do if u guide me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1.) Firstly create modal class (MyRequestClass) for your Post request from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

2.) Also create modal (MyResponseClass) for your server response from same site.

3.) Set values you want to send to your server by creating object of MyRequestClass.

4.) Then hit api using this method in your interface:

```
@POST("/provider/filter")
Call<MyResponseClass> sendDataToServer(@Body MyRequestClass myModal);
```

Comment: Are you sending values in header also?

Comment: Yes, I have added headers also. i think HttpUrlConnections should be used but i am not sure

Comment: @Suhas i think your JsonRequestBean is not correct. JsonRequestBean parameters or variable names should match with the request parameters you sending in Postman. Please correct your JsonRequestBean variables name same as Request parameters name. i hope it will be solved.

Comment: No, Vicky;( can you give me your mail iD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154207/discussion-between-suhas-and-vicky-kumar).

Comment: er.vickykumar323@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

your response class is wrong. 
it should be :

```
Response{
private Data[] data;

public Data[] getData ()
{
    return data;
}

public void setData (Data[] data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [data = "+data+"]";
}

public class Data
{
    private String id;

private String city_name;

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCity_name ()
{
    return city_name;
}

public void setCity_name (String city_name)
{
    this.city_name = city_name;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", city_name = "+city_name+"]";
}
}
}
```

retrofit call:

```
@POST("/lfs/city_name")
Call<Response> locData (@Body JsonRequestBean mRequest);
}
```

add value to keyword using setter method

Comment: Ok i'l try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

> remove /. from POST Method as retrofit base url ends with /. so your url
>   is now baseurl//lfs/city_name

```
    @POST("lfs/city_name")<----- change
Call<JsonResponseBean> locData (@Body JsonRequestBean mRequest);
```

> adding headers to request

```
  public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final String TAG = "RetrofitClient";

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        Retrofit retrofit = null;
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
// set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);



        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Licence", BuildConfig.Licence); // <-- this is the important line

                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        if (retrofit==null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getClient: base url  "+ BuildConfig.base_url);
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.base_url)
                    .client(httpClient.build())

                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static Retrofit getClientWithAdminBaseUrl() {
         Retrofit retrofit = null;
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.admin_base_url)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: if your api needs headers yes you should

Comment: if your api doesnt need header try sending it using formurlencoded https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded

Comment: Yes so i included them and from URL POV there was no issues but i need to use HttpUrlConnection that coding i don't know ;(

Comment: ERROR in Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Licence", BuildConfig.Licence); // <-- this is the important line ...... what is licence here?

Comment: use your header instead