# I'm migrating from HttpURLConnection to Retrofit 2 and sending data via POS doesn't work

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, httpurlconnection, pojo

I send data to a server using HttpURLConnection and it works correctly.

The JSON that I send is as follows:

```js
{
"name":"Product X",
   "desc":"abcdef",
    "barCode":"",
    "quantity":123,
    "esExtra":false,
    "idUnit":3,
    "idDept":13,
    "idCat":60,
    "idSubcat":0,
    "costP":1.96,
    "costS":2.69,
    "idEmp":3,
    "image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/Z\n",
    "taxes":[
     {
     "id":1
  }
 ]
}
```

For retrofit, the class associated with the JSON is the following:

```js
public class ActionRegisterProductService {
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("desc")
    public String desc;
    @SerializedName("barCode")
    public String barCode;
    @SerializedName("quantity")
    public Integer quantity;
    @SerializedName("esExtra")
    public Boolean esExtra;
    @SerializedName("idUnit")
    public Integer idUnit;
    @SerializedName("idDept")
    public Integer idDept;
    @SerializedName("idCat")
    public Integer idCat;
    @SerializedName("idSubcat")
    public Integer idSubcat;
    @SerializedName("costP")
    public Double costP;
    @SerializedName("costS")
    public Double costS;
    @SerializedName("idEmp")
    public Integer idEmp;
    @SerializedName("image")
    public String image;
    @SerializedName("taxes")
    public List<Taxes> listTaxes = null;

    public ActionRegisterProductService(
            String name,
            String desc,
            String barCode,
            int quantity,
            boolean esExtra,
            int idUnit,
            int idDept,
            int idCat,
            int idSubcat,
            double costP,
            double costS,
            int idEmp,
            String image,
            List<Taxes> listTaxes,
    ){
            this.name = name;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.barCode = barCode;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.esExtra = esExtra;
            this.idUnit = idUnit;
            this.idDept = idDept;
            this.idCat = idCat;
            this.idSubcat = idSubcat;
            this.costP = costP;
            this.costS = costS;
            this.idEmp = idEmp;
            this.image = image;
            this.listTaxes = listTaxes;
            }
    }


}
```

To send the data I do the following:

```js
 apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
                        ActionRegisterProductService  actionRegisterProductService  = 
new ActionRegisterProductService (
 "Product X",
 "abcd",
 "",
 123,
 false,
 5,
 1,
 3,
 0,
 1.23,
 4.25,
 3,
 "/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/Z\n",
 mylistTaxes,
 );
```

then the following is executed:

```js
Call<ActionRegisterProductService> call = apiInterface.createProduct(actionRegisterProductService);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<ActionRegisterProductService>() {
@Override
   public void onResponse(Call<ActionRegisterProductService> call, Response<ActionRegisterProductService> response) {
    ActionRegisterProductService user1 = response.body();
     if (response.raw().code() == 200 && response.raw().message().toLowerCase().equals("ok")) {

   }
}

 @Override
public void onFailure(Call<ActionRegisterProductService> call, Throwable t) {
                                                             
 call.cancel();
                           }

});
```

When executing the lines above the server responds correctly, ie response.raw ().Code is equal to 200 and response.raw.Message is equal to OK.

But when executing another method (from the old way) to obtain the created products, the product created with Retrofit doesn't appear. If it is done with the HttpURLConnection method, it works correctly, it is for that reason that I suspect that the JSON is not being created correctly.

apiInterface.createProduct is as follows:

```js
public interface APIInterface {
    @POST("Product")
    Call<ActionRegisterProductService> createProduct(@Body ActionRegisterProductService actionRegisterProductService);
}
```

Any suggestions or comments?

**UPDATE**:

It seems that I am not fulfilling a fundamental condition which indicates that there must be a class for sending data, such as one for reception (it does not necessarily have to be the same)

```js
Call<MyResponseClass> sendDataToServer(@Body MyRequestClass myModal);
```

[fundamental conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154156/how-to-post-json-using-retrofit-2-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: what does it mean **But when executing another method (from the old way) to obtain the created products, the product created with Retrofit doesn't appear**

Comment: I send the JSON by HttpURLConnection and the server responds correctly and then by checking if the product has been created, it is indeed there.

Comment: in question you have mentioned that you are getting response 200 by calling api using retrofit then where is the issue ?

Comment: The problem is that if the JSON is correct, the product should be created on the server. But this way send the data in an erroneous way by means of Retrofit, there is a response of 200 and OK, for example if name is null. With HttpURLConnection if name is null, the server shows me an error.

Comment: The question would be: How can I see the JSON that Retrofit created before sending it to the server?

Comment: use the [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Comment: One question, in response.body (), should the data be sent?

Answer (score 0):

In your APIClient add the gson converter factory like this `Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

if you don't find GsonConverterFactory add this dependency
`implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"`

Comment: If I think it is:
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


        return retrofit;

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when creating a class for the reception of the data. Once I did that, a response arrived from the server indicating a syntax error in the sending of data. I corrected that problem and it worked correctly.